# Is there a way to align the contents to appear exactly one below the other?

Tags: css, wordpress

The icons and the text has to be aligned so that they appear one below the other. Right now, it is displayed as

```
  Dubai, United Arab Emirates
Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates
        United Arab Emirates
```

I want them to appear as ;

```
    Dubai, United Arab Emirates
    Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates
    United Arab Emirates
```

What would be the CSS query to fix this?

I have already tried to use the float;, clear;, text-align, queries. But none of them have worked.

```html
<div class="post-options">
  <span class="cs-location">
    <i class="icon-map-marker"></i> 
    Dubai, United Arab Emirates 
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your HTML structure here , cause css requires a mimimal structure to have some effects

Comment: You can use the snippet button to make a mimimal snippet that reproduce your issue  help/explanation here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Welcome on SO ;)

Comment: Provide Your HTML structure so we can check what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to set width on both the `.post-title` and `.post-options` classes i.e. say width: 25%.

Right now the width of post-title is defined by the actual content which can vary, that's why you see that each location is offset in a different way.